# not found as file or resource in assets folder

Tags: android, android-assets

I have a question, why can't access a file in my assets folder?

**Folder**

[image]

**My code**

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.hackro.tutorials.myapplication/raw/comprobante.pdf");

String newPath = path.toString();

Resources res = getResources();

try {

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(newPath);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/evidencia.pdf"));
    AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();

    fields.setField("Referencia", referencia);

    fields.setField("Fecha y Hora", fechahora);
    fields.setField("Tipo", tipo);
    fields.setField("Operacion", operacion);
    fields.setField("no. tarjeta", tarjeta);
    fields.setField("vencimiento", vencimiento);
    fields.setField("monto", monto);
    fields.setField("concepto", concepto);
    fields.setField("Nombre", nombre);
    fields.setField("Autorizacion", autorizacion);


    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("error:   ", e.getMessage());
}
```

**Exception**

```
java.io.IOException: android.resource://com.hackro.tutorials.myapplication/raw/comprobante.pdf not found as file or resource.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

First, resources are not assets. You are attempting to use the `android.resource` scheme to access an asset as if it were a raw resource, and this will not work.

Second, you are constructing a `Uri`, then are converting that to a string, then are trying to wrap that in a `File` object. That will never work, for any type of `Uri`.

Third, neither resources nor assets are files on the filesystem of the device. They are files on the filesystem of your development machine. They are entries in the APK file on the device. You cannot get a `File` object pointing to a resource or an asset.

Use `getAssets()` on a `Context` (e.g., your `Activity` or `Service`) to get an `AssetManager`. Then, call `open("comprobante.pdf")` on that `AssetManager` to get an `InputStream` on the asset. Pass that to the `PdfReader` constructor and hope that your PDF library supports an `InputStream`.